# How to find if time is within A set of range?

Tags: c#, list, linq, datetime

I am creating an Attendance Application and I am looking for a way to check if their attendance logs is within an hour of their Schedule

Lets say Employee1 has a schedule of January 31, 2019 @ 00:30 but he arrives and checks in ahead of time so his logs state that he checks in at January 30, 2019 @ 23:45. So I am trying to find that if an employee logs in within an hour ahead or an hour late that will be his log in time. Like he can log in between Jan 30, 2019 23:30 till Jan 31, 2019 01:30.

What I did at the moment is that I have 4 more DateTime variables that handle these but it doesn't seem to work.

*So this is my Employee Class*

```
public class Emp1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime In { get; set; }
        public DateTime Out { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateTime1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateTime2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateTime3 { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateTime4 { get; set; }
    }
```

my *Actual Attendance Logs class*

```
public class Actual
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActualLog { get; set; }
        public int LogStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```

So this is my code on how I am populating my Employee Schedule

```
List<Emp1> em = new List<Emp1>();

                foreach (DataRow row in empContainer.Rows)
                {
                    em.Add(new Emp1()
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(row[0].ToString()),
                        In = Convert.ToDateTime(row[1].ToString()),
                        Out = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2].ToString()),
                        dateTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(row[1].ToString()).AddHours(1),
                        dateTime2 = Convert.ToDateTime(row[1].ToString()).AddHours(-1),
                        dateTime3 = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2].ToString()).AddHours(1),
                        dateTime4 = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2].ToString()).AddHours(-1)
                    });
                }
```

And this is my current LINQ statement to populate my DataGrid

```
public void Main()
        {
            List<Emp1> emps;
            List<Actual> actuals;

            actuals = emp.GetActual(@"C:\Users\IT\Desktop\Sample\SampleActual.dat");
            emps = GetEmpSched();



            var final = (from a1 in actuals
                         join a2 in actuals on a1.ID equals a2.ID
                         join t1 in emps on a1.ID equals t1.ID
                         join t2 in emps on a2.ID equals t2.ID
                         where ((a1.LogStatus == 0) && (a2.LogStatus == 1)) && ((t1.In == t2.In) && (t1.Out==t2.Out)) && ((t1.dateTime1 > a1.ActualLog) && (a1.ActualLog > t1.dateTime2)) && ((t2.dateTime3 > a2.ActualLog) && (a2.ActualLog > t2.dateTime4))
                         select new
                         {
                             User_ID = t1.ID,
                             Scheduled_In = t1.In,
                             Actual_Login = a1.ActualLog,
                             Scheduled_Out = t2.Out,
                             Actual_Out = a2.ActualLog
                         }).Distinct(). ToList();

            tbContainer = StaticClasses.ToDataTable(final);

            dgvAttendance.ItemsSource = emp.CalculateEmployeeAttendance(tbContainer);
        }
```

This is my employee schedule source

[image: Employee Schedule]

And this is my Employee Attendance Logs

[image: Attendance Logs]

As you see I have 4 extra DateTime variables that I just added to handle the extra or less hours, but it still doesn't work which I have no Idea why.

And this is the current output
[image: Actual Output]

So I am missing data because of my conditions, which should work fine but producing erroneous output.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Any answers that would help me out would be great. Thanks

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do. what exactly are you starting with, what is your expected output? also  Convert.ToDateTime(row[1].ToString()).AddHours(1) makes no sense. You have a datetime, you convert to string first, then you convert it back to datetime. It was datetime to begin with, why bother?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu beginner mistake, my expected output as I have said is that I want to check if there is an attendance log within an hour ahead or before of the scheduled shift of an employee. My primary problem is that when an employee has a schedule let's say 30 minutes after midnight and he comes early to Time in, it doesn't register. Thats why I have the AddHours function

Comment: I guess he used .ToString() because index of DataRow returns with an Object. it is Maybe more clever to use some other mechanism to access to cell data. Eg: Field extensions.
Anyway, it was not the question.
Do you really want to process this kind of data with one select? I guess a sequential processing can give you more space.

Comment: @sac1 I would love to have it on one select statement because the source actually of the data already comes from 2 files. But if its not possible, I am also looking at it.

Comment: @sac1 I just want to check if there is an attendance log within an hour ahead or before the scheduled shift.

Comment: I just recommend to do it sequential, because I am not sure  - I did not test - your result from join looks like as you expected

And you can solve midnight problem with tick comperasion 
 Math.Abs((dateTime2 - dateTime1).Ticks) > TimeSpan.FromHours(1).Ticks

Comment: @sac1 as you see I have made it on a LINQ statement, does Math.Abs work with LINQ?

Comment: @newboooooo As I see, there is no DB engine behind your code, so everything will be done in your executable. It will be not compiled to SQL or any other query language like EF. That's why I asked you about sequential. Because you need all data and you already parsed all data. No - or not major - performance issue.

Comment: @sac1 yea, this will be just processed on the fly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187634/discussion-between-sac1-and-newboooooo).

Comment: @sac1 seems to be working, but not yet that stable. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying the hard way, this should be more simple.

To compare the actual log In time with the scheduled one and check if it's within an hour you can just substract both and check the difference.

It's easy with c#:

```
    var scheduledLogIn = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
    var actualLogIn = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31, 8, 15, 27);

    var delay = (actualLogIn.TimeOfDay - scheduledLogIn).Duration();

    if (delay.TotalHours < 1)
    {
        // It's ok
    } else
    {
        // more than 1h earlier or late!
    }
```

If you are interested on checking if it's actually earlier or late, remove Duration and check if TotalHours is negative/positive.